# Pandas comparing dataframe with student results against historic quantiles

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes. One shows student test results  by class on two tests

```
import pandas as pd   
 results = pd.DataFrame({
    'id':[1,2,3],
    'class':[1,1,2],
    'test_1':[0.67,0.88,0.33],
    'test_2':[0.76,0.63,0.78]})
    results
```

> ```
>    id  class  test_1  test_2
> 0   1      1    0.67    0.76
> 1   2      1    0.88    0.63
> 2   3      2    0.33    0.78
> ```

The other shows quantiles by class and test based on previous semesters

```
quantiles = pd.DataFrame({'class':[1,2],
'test_1_0.25':[0.23,0.31],
'test_1_0.5':[0.54,0.67],
'test_1_0.75':[0.8,0.9],
'test_2_0.25':[0.23,0.31],
'test_2_0.5':[0.54,0.67],
'test_2_0.75':[0.8,0.9]})
```

> ```
>   class  test_1_0.25  test_1_0.5  test_1_0.75  test_2_0.25  test_2_0.5  \
> 0      1         0.23        0.54          0.8         0.23        0.54   
> 1      2         0.31        0.67          0.9         0.31        0.67
>
>    test_2_0.75  
> 0          0.8  
> 1          0.9
> ```

I would like to return a datarfame that tells me what quantile they place in. 0 if they are below 25, 1 if below 50, 2 if below 75, and 3 if above 75. So the output would look like this

> ```
>    id  test_1_quantile  test_2_quantile  
> 0   1                2                2   
> 1   2                3                1   
> 2   3                1                2
> ```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Second quantle for `test2` is `2`, because `class1` - so between `0.54  and 0.8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) both DataFrame, then loop be all test values and processing - first [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) by same `test`, add column for test values bellow .25 quantile, set new columns names for output range and compare by [`DataFrame.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html). Last change order of columns by `iloc` and get column name of first `True` value for replace `test` column:

```
df = pd.merge(results, quantiles, on='class')

for t in results.columns.difference(['id','class']):
    #print (t)
    df1 = df.filter(like=t)
    df1.insert(1, t + '_0', 0)
    df1.columns = [t] + list(range(4))
    #print (df1)
    a = df1.iloc[:, 1:].lt(df1[t], axis=0).iloc[:, ::-1].idxmax(axis=1)
    df[t] = a

print (df[results.columns])
   id  class  test_1  test_2
0   1      1       2       2
1   2      1       3       2
2   3      2       1       2
```

Comment: Thank you sir, this did what I needed it to do